# setInterval dojo example

Tags: javascript, dojo, setinterval

i'm new to dojo and in nned of some guidance...

i have a function that does something and i need it to run every x milliseconds... how can i achieve it with dojo?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Please describe the problem.

Comment: i have a function that does something and i need it to run every x milliseconds... how can i achieve it with dojo? (i use v1.7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In plain javascript (which you can use in dojo project), if you have a function `doIt()` that you want to call every 250ms, you would just use this:

```
var interval = setInterval(doIt, 250);
```

And, you can then stop it some time later with this:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

If you need to pass some arguments to `doIt()` like this `doIt(true, "go", 4)`, then you could code your interval like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    doIt(true, "go", 4);
}, 250);
```

If you want to use the `dojox.timing` functionality, then there's a reference for that [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/timing.html), with this code example in it:

```
dojo.require('dojox.timing');
var t = new dojox.timing.Timer(1000);
t.onTick = function(){
 console.info("One second elapsed");
}
t.onStart = function(){
 console.info("Starting timer");
}
t.start();
```

Comment: i know of `setInterval()` but there is a way to do it with dojo (dojox.timing.Timer.setInterval). that's what i'm looking for.
the official documentation is not sufficient for me and i couldn't find any useful examples online.

Comment: @levtatarov - This example looks pretty self explanatory to me: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/timing.html.  I added it to my answer.

Comment: this must be another way to it with dojo. i'll try it out. tnx

Comment: @levtatarov - FYI, I didn't know dojo at all.  Google is your friend here.

Comment: curious if there is a way to cancel the interval? the docs don't specify a way to do this.

Comment: @seth - Look at the second piece of code in my answer.